# Step by Step install plain hadoop cluster using Ambari

Tags: hadoop, ambari

Can anyone please let me know step by step instructions on how to install plain hadoop multi node cluster(**not HDP,Cloudera**) using Ambari. I tried google but got no help.

Thanks
Gaurav Gupta

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by 'plain hadoop'.

Answer (score 1):

Ambari requires a stack definition which describes what services are available and how to provision, manage, and monitor those services. This is exactly what HDP is, it's a stack definition provided by Hortonworks. If you don't want to use the HDP stack but **still** wish to use Ambari then you would have to define your own stack. You could take a look at the [Ambari Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Stacks+and+Services) to learn how to write a custom stack for your so called 'plain hadoop'.

Alternatively you could install 'plain hadoop' **without** Ambari by following the installation instructions on the [Apache Hadoop Site](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Installation).